# Single transaction to transfer everything?

Tags: transactions, ether, tokens, gas, myetherwallet

Is it possible (with MyEtherWallet or otherwise) to create a single transaction that moves all ether and tokens from one account to another in the interest of saving as much gas as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.
The long answer is that it would be possible to build a smart contract that does just that, but gas costs of deploying the contract and executing that function would be probably higher than just doing it separately.

Comment: You are right, you can use the constructor trick to save some deploying gas, but it is unlikely you will save much, because you have to previously approve the contract for every token you want to move.